# Electrical Force on 2 Line Charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

> Two line segments of length L are located in the x-y plane. One is on the x-axis between -L/2 and L/2. The second is parallel to the x-axis at y=L and again is between -L/2 and L/2. Each carries a uniformly distributed charge of +Q. What is the size and direction of the electrical force on each?

I've tried this problem and it seems like I am making it more complicated than it needs to be. Is there any need to integrate over the length of the line segment? The force exerted between the two should be repulsive since they have the same positive charge, Q. If the question were asking the total force on the system as a whole, wouldn't it be 0?

Comment: Yes, you need to integrate along the length of the segment -- the distance between the charges on both rods isn't a constant, so you can't apply Coulomb's Law for point charges directly.

Answer (score 2):

The direction of force is easy as the like charge indicates that the lines will repel one another, thus the force on the upper line has a positive y-component and the force on the lower has a negative y-component. The symmetry of the problem indicates that there is no x-component of force in either case, thus the force is along the y axis for the upper and the lower but in opposite directions.
Similarly, symmetry indicates that the magnitudes of the force will be equal for both, so you only need to find the value for one of the lines. To do this: first calculate the electric field as a function of (x,y) for one of the lines while neglecting the presence of the other; you can do this by integration. Using the calculated function for the electric field, find the force on the other line by integrating E(x,y) dq over the line, where E(x,y) is the earlier calculated field.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. I'll give it try and see what I come up with. When I first calculate the electric field, what should I use as my field point? Does it matter? I could just use Gauss's law and find E(s), where s is a radial vector away from the line. But, then that would probably make it more difficult to integrate E(s)dq over the line.

Comment: Your initial field point should be an arbitrary point (x,y) in the plane so that you get the electric field as a function of space rather than a number at some particular point. You cannot use Gauss' law for this problem because there is not enough symmetry to employ that helpful tool unfortunately; this is because the lines are of finite length. To use Gauss' law here you would have to have infinite lines of charge so that the problem would exhibit cylindrical symmetry.